# Python Dataframe Reshaping

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement

I have a python pandas dataframe that can be simplified as follow:

```
python
df= pd.DataFrame([['January','Monday',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,1,20],['January','Monday',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,2,25],['February','Monday',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,1,15],\
      ['February','Monday',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,2,20],['February','Monday',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,3,25],['March','Tuesday',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,1,50],\
      ['March','Wednesday',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,1,75]],columns = ['Month','Day','Data1','Data2', 'Data3','Count','Initial_Data'])
```

```
     Month        Day  Data1  Data2  Data3  Count  Initial_Data
0   January     Monday    NaN    NaN    NaN      1            20
1   January     Monday    NaN    NaN    NaN      2            25
2  February     Monday    NaN    NaN    NaN      1            15
3  February     Monday    NaN    NaN    NaN      2            20
4  February     Monday    NaN    NaN    NaN      3            25
5     March    Tuesday    NaN    NaN    NaN      1            50
6     March  Wednesday    NaN    NaN    NaN      1            75
```

The aim/goal of new data frame: I would like to have the data classified by month and day. I would like to fill column Data1, Data2 and Data3 with figure from Initial_Data. So for example for Month January and Day Monday, Data1 = 20, Data2 = 25 and Data3 stays as NaN because month January and Day Monday has highest Count = 2. For month February and day Monday I would like to have Data1 = 15, Data2 = 20 and Data3 = 25, this is because month February and day Monday has highest Count=3. For month March day Tuesday, I would like to have Data1 = 50, Data2 and Data3 = NaN and for Month March day Wednesday I would like to have Data1 = 75 and DAta2 = Data3 = NaN because they have highest Count = 1. The Final datafame shall look like this:

```
      Month        Day  Data1  Data2  Data3
0   January     Monday     20   25.0    NaN
1   January     Monday     20   25.0    NaN
2  February     Monday     15   20.0   25.0
3  February     Monday     15   20.0   25.0
4  February     Monday     15   20.0   25.0
5     March    Tuesday     50    NaN    NaN
6     March  Wednesday     75    NaN    NaN
```

I tried to use if statement, but it does not work since I cant find solution to fill all three columns (Data1,Data2 and Data3). Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
df2 = df.set_index(['Month','Day','Count'])['Initial_Data'].unstack().add_prefix('Data').reset_index()
df.merge(df2, on=['Month','Day'], suffixes=('_x',''))[df.columns]
```

Output:

```
      Month        Day  Data1  Data2  Data3  Count  Initial_Data
0   January     Monday   20.0   25.0    NaN      1            20
1   January     Monday   20.0   25.0    NaN      2            25
2  February     Monday   15.0   20.0   25.0      1            15
3  February     Monday   15.0   20.0   25.0      2            20
4  February     Monday   15.0   20.0   25.0      3            25
5     March    Tuesday   50.0    NaN    NaN      1            50
6     March  Wednesday   75.0    NaN    NaN      1            75
```

Details:

First, use `set_index` and `unstack` the inner most index to move to 'Count' in to columns.  Thus reshaping the dataframe.  Then add 'Data' prefix to column headers.

Next, we need to `merge` or join the two dataframe together based on Month and day columns.

Comment: Could you add a little more explanation exactly how this works?

Comment: @Ryan it is best you take the statement and run it part by part to see what is going on.  The hardest part o understand if you aren't a database person is the concept of create a Cartesian product create multiples on duplicate keys with the `merge` method.

Comment: Is there anything I can read / study to figure out what you mean by Cartesian product? I've run it step by step but that's the line I don't quite get.

Comment: Try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product  or https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-cartesian-joins.htm

Answer (score 0):

Here was my answer, but Scott beat me to it with a much better one.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['January','Monday',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,1,20],\
    ['January','Monday',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,2,25],\
    ['February','Monday',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,1,15],\
    ['February','Monday',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,2,20],\
    ['February','Monday',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,3,25],\
    ['March','Tuesday',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,1,50],\
    ['March','Wednesday',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,1,75]],
    columns = ['Month','Day','Data1','Data2', 'Data3','Count','Initial_Data'])

new = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Month','Day','Data1','Data2', 'Data3'])

for ridx, row in df.iterrows():
    new.loc[ridx] = [row['Month'], row['Day'], np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]
    if row['Count'] == 1:
        new.loc[new.index[ridx], 'Data1'] = row['Initial_Data']
    if row['Count'] == 2:
        new.loc[new.index[ridx], 'Data2'] = row['Initial_Data']
        new.loc[new.index[ridx-1], 'Data2'] = row['Initial_Data']
        new.loc[new.index[ridx], 'Data1'] = new.loc[new.index[ridx-1], 'Data1']
    if row['Count'] == 3:
        new.loc[new.index[ridx], 'Data3'] = row['Initial_Data']
        new.loc[new.index[ridx-1], 'Data3'] = row['Initial_Data']
        new.loc[new.index[ridx-2], 'Data3'] = row['Initial_Data']
        new.loc[new.index[ridx], 'Data1'] = new.loc[new.index[ridx-1], 'Data1']
        new.loc[new.index[ridx], 'Data2'] = new.loc[new.index[ridx-1], 'Data2']

print(new)
```

---

```
      Month        Day Data1 Data2 Data3
0   January     Monday    20    25   NaN
1   January     Monday    20    25   NaN
2  February     Monday    15    20    25
3  February     Monday    15    20    25
4  February     Monday    15    20    25
5     March    Tuesday    50   NaN   NaN
6     March  Wednesday    75   NaN   NaN
```